# Heoku R14 Memory quota exceeded at 512 on a 2X Dyno

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a 2x Dyno (1024M Memory), but my Node app gets the error below when I exceed 512M Mem.  Is there anything I can do to prevent that?  Is there something I might be missing in upgrading from 1X to 2X?

```
» 30 Apr 2015 14:54:38.334 2015-04-30 18:54:37.898933+00:00 heroku run.4008 - - Process running mem=555M(108.6%)
» 30 Apr 2015 14:54:38.409 2015-04-30 18:54:37.899176+00:00 heroku run.4008 - - Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) Critical
```

Comment: What is the result of `heroku ps` ?

Comment: === web (2X): `node server/server.js`
web.1: idle 2015/04/29 17:44:37

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the brief snippet of your logs it looks like the process causing the memory error is not a web dyno, but a one-off dyno that is spun up when running a command with `heroku run`. The [default size for one-off dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#one-off-dyno-size) is 1x and you have to specify a different size:

```
$ heroku run --size=2X
```

If the job is kicked off by heroku scheduler, you can edit the dyno size via the scheduler dashboard. Each job on the dashboard has a dyno size option that you can select.

Comment: It's a process kicked off by Heroku scheduler.  How can I change the Dyno size there?

Comment: you can change the dyno size in the scheduler dashboard. (answer edited)